PYPMML Model is returning "None" in the responses when we upgrade to latest version 17
We are using pypmml package in our flask application. Recently we observed a vulnerability in commons-text-1.6.jar (this comes in site packages when we install pypmml). Vulnerability which exists in commons-text versions >= 1.5, < 1.10.0.
To mitigate this vulnerability, we upgraded the package version to 0.9.17 from 0.9.12. With the latest version common-text version is 1.10. But, The model has started giving "None" in the responses when we call predict method with our request data. Responses are as expected with the old version.
Can some one please help?
enter image description here
I tried downgrading package back to 0.9.12 and its working as expected, when I downgraded to first ever version of this package 0.9.0, then also, it is working. I cannot use lower versions of this package since its having common text jar file vulnerability.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@СергейКох, updated the description, let me know what further details are required
